# Jquery Datatables update data

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, datatables

I am using socket IO to always have my data update and Jquery Datatables to show it.
However, to give the data to my datable, I am using     `socket.on( 'nuevatable', function(consolidado_data) { console.log("Entro a actualizar la data en JS"); table.rows.add(dataSet).draw();`
Which works great but I send all the data, and basicaly my datatable have the same data added everytime my socket send data which is every second. I realy don't know how to only update the data with the new or in another case, just make the add as an inner add where only new rows are kept in the datatable.

Anyone can tell me how i could do that ?

This is my whole code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var socket = io('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('update', 'ejecutar');
    }, 1000);

var dataSet;
var table;

socket.on( 'nuevatable', function(consolidado_data) {
    console.log("Entro a escribir la data en JS");
    console.log("1: "+consolidado_data);
    var newData = JSON.stringify(consolidado_data);
    dataSet = JSON.parse(newData);
    console.log("2: "+dataSet);
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("3: "+dataSet);
    table = $('#dtHorizontalExample').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { data: "solicitudes_id" },
            { data: "id_user" },
            { data: "tipouso" },
            { data: "tipoauto" },
            { data: "credito" },
            { data: "entidadcrediticia" },
            { data: "id_auto" },
            { data: "fecha" },
            { data: "canalinput" },
            { data: "ciudadcompra" },
            { data: "hora" },
            { data: "nombre" },
            { data: "appellidos" },
            { data: "numdocumento" },
            { data: "numtelefono" },
            { data: "correo" },
            { data: "tipolicencia" },
            { data: "tiempolicencia" },
            { data: "trabajoaplicativo" },
            { data: "tipodocumento" },

        ],
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "search":"Buscar:",
            "info":"Mostrando _START_ hasta _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords":"No se encontraron coincidencias",
            "processing":"Procesando...",
            "loadingRecords":"Cargando...",
            "infoEmpty":"Mostrando 0 hasta 0 de 0 registros",
            "infoFiltered":"(resultado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            "emptyTable":"No hay data disponible en la tabla",
            "paginate": {
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous":"Anterior",
                "first":"Primera",
                "last":"Ultima",
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on( 'nuevatable', function(consolidado_data) {
    console.log("Entro a actualizar la data en JS");
    table.rows.add(dataSet).draw();
    });

});</script>
```

I tried adding `table.clear();` before adding data, and it works but you can't interact with the table because it is always changing the data.